# C++ iptables libipq create multiple queues at same time

Tags: c++, message-queue, iptables

How can I create two different ip_queues, running at the same time? One of it can listen for incoming packets on one port and another can listen for outgoing packets on the same port.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It cannot be done :(